# Session Destroy error

Tags: php

I am trying to destroy a session on click of logout but that is not working.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
{ 
   session_destroy();   
   session_unset();     
   header('Location:Login2.php');
 }
 else
 {
    echo "error";
 }
 ?>
```

It goes in else part means display error.

Comment: Then `$_SESSION['user_name']` is clearly not set.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$_SESSION['user_name']`?

Comment: @RafaelBarros No..Value of $_SESSION['user_name'] is not getting..

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of un-needed code. For instance your logout link will only be shown if user is actually logged in right so there really is no point in the `if-else` statement.

Shorten it to just:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:Login2.php');

?>
```

I mean if you are going to destroy the session there really is no point in checking weather or not user is logged in. Lets say the path http://yourdomain.com/logout.php leads to this script well if user is not logged in and he somehow visits this path nothing really happens but if he is logged in you really should not care if the SESSION variable is set since you are going to destroy it regardless.

Comment: The code which u have given is also not working.When i click on back,still it is going in previous page.

Comment: Well you defined header() redirect so it destroys the session and it takes you to Login2.php if you don't want the redirect then simply remove the header() function. As for the session there really is nothing that could not work there.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `session_destroy()` makes the need for `session_unset()` repetitive and unnecessary. Also call `die()` after `header()` or else everything else gets executed still and the redirect fails.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
{ 
   session_destroy();   
   header('Location: Login2.php');
   die();
}
else
{
   echo "error";
}
?>
```

There is a lot of redundant logic and code still so here is the optimal solution:

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();   
header('Location: Login2.php');
die();
?>
```